# Creating new Android test purchase accounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-developer-api, android-inapp-purchase

I have followed the following docs in my attempt to create new test/sandbox accounts for doing test purchases in my app(s), but it has yet to work correctly.

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777
- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334
- https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

I would like to mention that the existing accounts we have (one with US store setting, another with UK store), work perfectly fine in the apps to make test purchases. It is my desire to create more accounts, to spread among my growing QA comrades, so we're not constantly sharing accounts.

There does not seem to be any start-to-finish instructions, so this is what I've done do far:

- Created a new gmail
- Signed into that account with a Google Device
- Added a Credit Card to the account (expecting that it will not get charged when purchasing in the apps)
- On the Play Console, added the email to the appropriate email list
- There is an existing closed/internal test track (since the application is unpublished), so confirmed it was using that list -- **do I need to stop and recreate the track to accept new email list changes?**
- Followed a link (taken from the Play Console) to enroll in the Closed Track